# How many possible HTTP links of length n are there?

Tags: url, counting

Here by HTTP links I mean URLs that start with `http` (note that this includes `https`).

Assuming that such links can be no longer than `n` and can only contain characters out of an alphabet of size `t`, a naive upper-bound is `pow(t, n)`. A quick [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=length+of+urls) says that `n=2048`, if we let `t=95-26=19` which are all the printable ASCII characters minus the capital letters then the upper-bound is,

```
pow(19, 2048) < pow(2, 8700)
```

Could someone who knows more about URLs improve or refute this bound?

Why do I care? Well, I thought about writing a URL shortner and wondered how many possible URLs there maybe anyways.